# Is there a limit on Microsoft Exchange 2003 connected mobile devices?

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, exchange-2003

Good Morning,

I'm wondering if there is a limit on how many mobile devices can connect to Microsoft Exchange 2003 on Windows Server 2003?

We have around 10 mobile devices connect to our Exchange which work absolutely fine, however I have a new laptop, iphone and ipad to access the Exchange and it's not allowing any of them to connect...

I have even tried using the exact details we know work on another device and it won't allow the connection either, even though the details are identical.

So back to my question, are there any limitations on Microsoft Exchange for external mobile devices?

I look forward to hearing your questions.

Kind Regards,
Shaun

Comment: Version of Exchange, including service pack level? Are these devices connecting to the same mailboxes as current devices, or new ones? What happens when you try?

Comment: @RobM Service Pack 2 and Exchange System Version: 6.5.7638.1 ... They are new users but i've tried with an old user on a new device and I get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

For exchange 2007 there are some [obscure limitations](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc540453%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx#OutConn) on the server based on tcp port limits.
For exchange 2010 there is a limit on the amount of connections a single user can have [and the default limit is 10.](http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2010/compliance-policies-archiving/exchange-2010-client-throttling-policies.html)

However it doesn't really matter what kind of connection it is, mobile or otherwise.
Exchange can throttle the amount of concurrent client-connections to a mailbox, however this is only for active connections. Meaning your new devices are probably not incurring any kind of limit.

Judging by your question, I would not look at the exchange server, but at the client setup.
You can use [the Microsoft connectivity tester](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/) to see what the problem is in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the information, So could can I increase the default limit?

Comment: @ShaunS As you added that you're running exchange 2003 SP2, I don't think you're actually reaching any kind of limit.

Comment: any idea on the issue then, the connection test comes back with an SSL issue but this has been worked around on the other devices and shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: `1.` The Exchange 2010 limit listed here is `per user`, not per Exchange server. `2.` How are these users connecting? IMAP, POP, EAS? `3.` What do the Exchange event and web server logs show? `4.` What are the symptoms of the problem?

Comment: @joeqwerty Indeed, the limit is per user. I'll update my answer if it wasn't clear. However as, since I started writing the answer, the OP has stated that he's using 2003, I don't think it's relevant (and am doubting if the answer should be deleted)

Comment: Oh, Exchange 2003. I missed that as well.